# google finance stock prices

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("ABC","all",today()-30,today(),"Daily")
```

This returns daily stock price info for ABC for the last 30 days. Is there a way to stagger the output so it only returns every 2nd day like:

```
Jan 24 price
Jan 26 price
Jan 28 price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CHOOSEROWS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13196659) function:

```cpp
=LET(data,GOOGLEFINANCE("ABC","all",today()-30,today(),Daily),
     CHOOSEROWS(data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)/2,1,1,2)))
```

You could also use [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) with the **skipping** clause:

```cpp
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABC","all",today()-30,today(),Daily),"skipping 2")
```